# Percentage of variance explained by predictors changing with order

Tags: regression, anova, linear, percentage

Let's supose the following database:

```
Y <- c(-30.36112,-32.34913,-18.00248,-29.44684,-57.76149,-48.07038,-54.64416,-52.68383,-52.32142,-48.50880,-50.63648,-48.50245,-46.04008,-48.01171,-52.40914,-59.27359,-57.76627,-56.63295,-53.69201,-43.69572,-47.29603)
VAR1 <- c(6.678268,6.967716,6.454398,7.101005,8.093585,7.990962,8.195695,8.056878,7.411791,7.242391,7.812364,7.702516,7.449701,7.605790,8.026065,7.429703,7.323534,7.469040,7.451037,7.268307,6.887991)
VAR2 <- c(-15.18045,-14.04796,-10.86249,-18.02701,-22.58593,-18.23110,-26.21489,-26.40168,-23.89198,-21.83521,-24.72966,-25.30072,-26.84327,-28.56968,-26.96086,-32.41178,-32.56032,-30.10673,-28.03696,-22.79052,-28.22369)
DATA <- data.frame(Y,VAR1,VAR2)
```

When I try to determine the percentage of variance explained for each variable, I can use two codes, but the results are different:

CODE I (Order of the explanatory variables in the model: VAR1 and VAR2)

```
c1 <- lm(DATA$Y~VAR1+VAR2)
c1ANN <- anova(c1)
c1ANss <- c1ANN$"Sum Sq"
print(cbind(c1ANN,PctExp=c1ANss/sum(c1ANss)*100))
```

Result:
[image]

CODE II (Order of the explanatory variables in the model: VAR2 and VAR1)

```
 c2 <- lm(DATA$Y~VAR2+VAR1)
    c2ANN <- anova(c2)
    c2ANss <- c2ANN$"Sum Sq"
    print(cbind(c2ANN,PctExp=c2ANss/sum(c2ANss)*100))
```

[image]

As it can be seen, the percentages have varied (last column). How can I deal with this problem in order to obtain the appropriate percentages?

Comment: Your variables are not orthogonal, hence no way to decouple variance explained. You need to use type2 or type 3 anova tables, but these won’t sum to the model SSR. Personally I would abandon this calculation unless you can identify a relevant variable ordering

Comment: How can I determine if my variables are or not orthogonal?? Thanks!!

Comment: One method: when they are orthogonal, their order in the ANOVA table doesn't matter!  Another method: apply the definition: "orthogonal" means their dot product (after centering them, because your model includes an intercept) is zero.

Comment: For example, if I have three variables and the percentage doesn't vary when I change the order of the predictor variables in ANOVA I can assume my variables are orthogonal? I mean, those three variables appear to be correlated but the percentages don't change when I modify the order...